# Advanced gnuplot terminals and softwares

Tags: gnuplot, data-visualization

I am definitely puzzled by the capabilities of the existing terminals for gnuplot (wxt, ...). It's quite impossible to edit quickly the chart on the interface (change color of one curve, hide one curve, export in eps with the current rendering (without switching terminals) etc...).
The "windows" term has some nice feature (linestyle editing, etc...) but I am still waiting for something more "complete".

Some operations like "hiding a line" are non-intuitive for the gnuplot command language (actually the only solution that I know is to rewrite the plot command) and that's why I am looking for a terminal that will leverage some specific intermediate representation of the plotted object to allow the user to change quickly the design.

Do you have any information about this kind of tools ?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I can't post more than two links because I'm a new-ish user here...

A quick search reveals several (probably abandoned) projects with similar parity to what you're asking for:

- [UniGNUPlot -Graphic GNUPlot front-end](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unicalculus), last update in 2009-07-17
- [JAVA gnuplot GUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jgp/), last update in 2010-04-19
- XGFE, last known **update in 1999-01-01** and probably best avoided due to its age...

Honestly, I'd recommend something like QtiPlot (which also has the advantage of being cross platform) which is your typical "data analysis and scientific visualisation solution". I know it's not of the same paradigm as gnuplot, but it's easy to use.

If you would insist on using gnuplot as the backend, then an interesting perl wrapper called gplot (search sourceforge) exists that you can call from the command line. From the website, the syntax seems straightforward

```
# plot 3 sets of data, specify colors and points
gplot.pl -color green -point uptriangle   1a.data \
    -color blue  -point box          2a.data \
    -color green -point circle       3a.data
```

but again, this is quite dated (last update 2009-07-17).

The major issue for these older gnuplot front ends is that gnuplot had a change of syntax for a few features (such as line color and style) a few years ago. I can't seem to find the precise version at which it changed at the moment, but the change did happen. Depending on how willing you are to change the source code of these wrappers, I do not imagine much tweaking would be needed.